# MPICH2, the failure of one process will crash all other processes

Tags: mpi, mpich

I use MPICH2. When I launch processes with mpiexec, the failure of one process will crash all other processes. How to avoid this?

Comment: Don't avoid it! That is the desired behaviour in 99.9% of the cases. Why would you want otherwise?

Comment: We want to implement fault-recovery: one process crash we just restart this one.

Comment: Well, you can't since MPI doesn't support it. Fault tolerance has been a topic of research in the MPI community for decades, and was expected to land in MPI 3.0, which it didn't. Maybe for MPI 4.0...

Comment: You question is a little generic, there's an overview of recent efforts here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23919726/491687

Answer (score 4):

In MPICH, there is a flag called `-disable-auto-cleanup` which will prevent the process manager from automatically cleaning up all processes when a single process fails.

However, MPI itself does not have much support for fault tolerance and this is something that the Fault Tolerance Working Group is working on adding in a future version of the MPI Standard.

For now, the best you can do is change the default MPI Error Handler away from `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL`, which causes all processes to abort, to something else like `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN` which would return the error code to the application and allow it to do something else. However, you're not likely to be able to communicate anymore after a failure has occurred, especially if you are trying to use collective communication.